A novel about an alien visiting the Earth and comparison to his planet
It is a sci fi novel I’m looking for. It’s written in the same context that The Hitchhiker’s guide to the Galaxy is. There is another book in a similar writing style called Greegs and Ladders, but that is not it. It’s been five to 7 years I read it online. So, I think it is recent like in the 2000’s.
An alien visits Earth. He can resemble a human and even have physical relationships with human females. He invents things.
He comes from a planet that has these purple tube creatures. Once the purple tube creatures watched something on Earth that made them jealous of human females. The purple tube females wanted to wear lipstick. They got freaky, had orgies and danced to the song “They’re coming to take to me away ha- ha”.
The ocean is made of milk and the beaches churn the milk into butter and cheese. Cows from Earth get online and download it so their utters will fill with milk.

https://genius.com/Napoleon-xiv-this-is-planet-earth-lyrics

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

I would guess this is The Alien's Guide to Planet Earth by James F. Coyle.

Bakir Breezlebob was one of the first generation Mammarians to migrate to earth but he had to adopt a human form to fit it with earth society. Which was why he chose a very common earth name of course.  His natural shape was that of a large round purple tube. He arrived as a tourist 2000 years ago but due to a union dispute between spacecraft pilots and management he got temporarily stranded. The dispute is not yet resolved. He has been married 78 times and claims he has women nearly figured out. This book starts by explaining how he adjusted to Earth conditions then goes on to describe a number of his marriages and world travels in a highly humorous manner.

I cannot find a copy to check the details, but the description seems very close. I would guess it is a self published book as I can find very little about it. It does not seem to be available online at the moment, though you can get it for free if you subscribe to Kindle Unlimited. If you can remember the web site where you read it you might be able to get it from the Wayback Machine.
Later
I have found the description of the book on Coyle's web site, and it is definitely the book you remember. The extract there mentions the cows and seas of milk:

It all started with an intergalactic love affair between the planet of Mammary in the Milky Way and the bovine cows on planet earth. Mammary females have four udders and they were terribly upset to discover some 2000 years ago that cows only had one udder. This they felt was grossly unfair and a committee was formed to redress this anomaly. It was decided that as Mammary had oceans filled with milk (instead of salt water) then they would transfer at midnight each night a top-up to all of earth's cows so by one minute past midnight all earth cows would have full udders. This was achieved by a sort of intergalactic email attachment which of course explains why we see so many cows in internet cafes these days updating their email addresses so they don't miss out!

